# Build V8 from source failing at gclient

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, build, v8

I wanted to try building Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine from source (I'm on Windows, so that adds to the pain) and I followed [This Guide](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-v8-on-windows-and-not-go-mad-6347c69aacd4) which walks through how to build V8. I follow the instructions as closely as I can, but when I run `$ gclient`, I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Program.
Could not extract Python version from manifest.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 99, in <module>
    import urlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'
```

I have even tripple checked my `PATH` ENV_VAR and everything is correct, so why is this happenning, and how do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`depot_tools` does not support spaces in installation path

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you take this across the finish line by adding how to use this information to solve the problem?